# Rails: Create association-through record via link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I have these models:

```
class Users < ActiveRecord::Base      
  has_many  :members
  has_many  :organizations, :through => :members
end

class Organizations < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_many  :members
  has_many  :users, :through => :members 
end

class Members < ActiveRecord::Base 
 belongs_to :organizations
 belongs_to :users
end
```

I would like to create a Member record as follows:

1. A user logs in
2. Navigates to a specific organization's 'show' page
3. Clicks on a link labeled 'Join'

I've read through several posts on the site asking similar questions; however, most are when one of the records is being created at the same time. Here is what I've tried:

In my organization's controller I created a join method:

```
# PATCH/PUT /organizations/1/join
def join
  @membership = @organization.members.new(user_id: current_user.id)
  if @membership.save
    flash[:success] = "Your have successfully joined #{@organization.name}!"
    redirect_to @organization
  else
    flash[:error] = "There was an error."
    render 'show'
  end
end
```

In my routes file, I added a join link:

```
resources :organizations do
  member do
    post :join
  end
end
```

On my organization's show page, I added a link as follows:

```
<% if @organization.members.where("user_id = ?", @current_user).exists? %>
  # Unjoin link
<% else %>
  <%= link_to 'Join!', join_organization_path,
                       :method => "post" %>
<% end %>
```

Here is my server log error:

```
Started POST "/organizations/2/join"
Processing by OrganizationsController#join as HTML
Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"...=", "id"=>"2"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1ms

NoMethodError (undefined method `members' for nil:NilClass):
app/controllers/organizations_controller.rb:47:in `join'
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: So What seems to be the issue here? What is not working?

Comment: I keep getting the flash error, not the flash success.

Comment: Can you share the server log generated, when you click on Join button. Add it in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the instance variable `@organization` in `join` method.

```
def join
  @organization = Organization.find(params[:id]) ## Set @organization
  @membership = @organization.members.new(user_id: current_user.id)
  if @membership.save
    flash[:success] = "Your have successfully joined #{@organization.name}!"
    redirect_to @organization
  else
    flash[:error] = "There was an error."
    render 'show'
  end
end
```

You are getting `NoMethodError (undefined method 'members' for nil:NilClass)` error because `@organization` instance variable is nil (not set) and you are calling `members` method on `nil` object.

If you have a `before_action` callback setup in your controller to set `@organization` variable then you can just add `join` as an option in it.

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick. I ended up just including the join method in my before_action :set_organization (private method).

Comment: in my? I think you mean to say before_action callback. If thats true, then thats the preferable way (Added in the answer) BUT I didn't see any callbacks related code shared in your Question so to better explain the problem I set @organization in the `join` action.